# Set Theory: Set of limit ordinals does not exist

Tags: ordinals

I am trying to show that a set of limit ordinals do not exists where X as a limit ordinal cannot be a set. Can anyone explain why you can't get a set of limit ordinals?

Comment: $\{\omega,\omega+\omega\}$ is **a** set of limit ordinals. I suspect that you’re being asked to show that the set of **all** limit ordinals does not exist; is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I'm trying to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well kwown that $\operatorname{Ord}$, the class of all ordinals, is not a set.

Write $L$ for the class of limit ordinals. We have a surjective functional $F : L \mapsto \operatorname{Ord}$ given by $\lambda \mapsto \alpha \textrm{ such that }\aleph_\alpha = |\lambda|$. Hence, $L$ can't be a set because if it were then the image of $F$, i.e. $\operatorname{Ord}$, would be a set.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof that goes like Euclid's proof of the infinitude of the set of primes. For every ordinal $\alpha$, there is a limit ordinal strictly bigger, $\alpha + \omega$. The union of a set of ordinals is an ordinal. So if the class of limit ordinals were a set $LO$, we could take $\bigcup LO + \omega$, a strictly larger limit ordinal, which contradicts $LO$ containing all the limit ordinals.